# MySql generating the same UUID when INSERT INTO... SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I have this bug happening only on the production server (of course).
I'm not able to replicate this on any machine.

Let's say I have to perform a query made like this

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table(UUID, Name, Surname) SELECT UUID(), Name, Surname FROM other_table
```

I expect to have a different UUID for any new generated row, that is exactly what happens in any environment. Except production.

There, if I run that query, MySQL generates all identical UUID. Looks like that, instead of generating a new one for every row, it runs the function only once and then replicates the value.

I'm pretty sure it's due to some kind of configuration, but I can't understand which one.

Also, it might not be strictly MySQL related: if I run the query from my PC but on the production server using SQLyog, the query works fine and generates all different UUIDs.

Could it be PHP fault? I'm currently using mysqli driver.

Just to make it clear, if I run this query from my PC

```sql
SELECT UUID()
FROM (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS id
     ) i
```

the result is

```
bb79716f-f0ba-11e9-a154-f23c91fbfa4a
bb79717a-f0ba-11e9-a154-f23c91fbfa4a
bb79717c-f0ba-11e9-a154-f23c91fbfa4a
bb79717e-f0ba-11e9-a154-f23c91fbfa4a
bb79717f-f0ba-11e9-a154-f23c91fbfa4a
bb797181-f0ba-11e9-a154-f23c91fbfa4a
bb797183-f0ba-11e9-a154-f23c91fbfa4a
bb797185-f0ba-11e9-a154-f23c91fbfa4a
bb797187-f0ba-11e9-a154-f23c91fbfa4a
bb797189-f0ba-11e9-a154-f23c91fbfa4a
```

But if I run the same query using PHP on the server, the result is

```
0aef9b78-f0bc-11e9-bfe5-7a7919257c79
0aef9b78-f0bc-11e9-bfe5-7a7919257c79
0aef9b78-f0bc-11e9-bfe5-7a7919257c79
0aef9b78-f0bc-11e9-bfe5-7a7919257c79
0aef9b78-f0bc-11e9-bfe5-7a7919257c79
0aef9b78-f0bc-11e9-bfe5-7a7919257c79
0aef9b78-f0bc-11e9-bfe5-7a7919257c79
0aef9b78-f0bc-11e9-bfe5-7a7919257c79
0aef9b78-f0bc-11e9-bfe5-7a7919257c79
0aef9b78-f0bc-11e9-bfe5-7a7919257c79
```

Comment: tried in db-fiddle, its working as expected https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=h90C4RGw1L

Comment: I know, works good on any machine. Except my server 

Comment: Which PHP versions and MySQL versions are you using?

Comment: MySQL 5.6.45-log
PHP 5.6.40 (I know, I know, we are in the process of upgrading everything)

Comment: Just tried with PHP 7.2, same issue

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the mysql extension. Using the old, deprecated mysql instead of mysqli solves the issue.

Comment: Have you enabled ```MySQL``` ```query caching``` in your ```php.ini``` file?

Comment: It is because of utf8 charset https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12774 please see this if it works

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon same issue with MySQL and was trying to work with the solution proposed by @bimbo1989.

I spent a good hour trying different solutions, and it turns out, these UUIDs just looked the same, but actually, three characters were granting the uniqueness (6,7,8).

Make sure if the UUIDs are same or just look such.

Comment: In my case I'm 100% they were the same 

Comment: @devaga, good observation.... I spent almost half a day on this and finally after reading your reply I found different results as mentioned by you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sushil I am truly happy then :) Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Not really the perfect answer to the question, but if anybody has the same problem it can be solved with a workaround.
Just create a "new_uuid" function in MySQL, in use it instead of the built-in one.
This way

```
CREATE FUNCTION new_uuid() RETURNS VARCHAR(36) CHARSET utf8 BEGIN   RETURN UUID();  END;
```

Then you can just use it instead of UUID()

```
SELECT new_uuid()
```

And it will correctly return different UUIDs in case you have multiple rows.

This is the only approach I got working to solve my issue. No idea why :)